# JNA: Accessing Static Methods When There Are Multiple Classes In Single Dll

Tags: java, jna

I have implemented native function call by JNA by following the basic scenario below and it worked as expected:

```
/* HelloWorld.java */

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class HelloWorld {
    public interface CTest extends Library {
        public void helloFromC();
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        CTest ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);
        ctest.helloFromC();
    }
}
```

Now I have dll with multiple classes and each class has some static methods. I have an example for C# but I could not find a way to call these methods from Java:

Here is sample C# Code:

```
//Assembly Test.CommonLibrary.dll
using System;
namespace Test.CommonLibrary
{
    public class Parameters
    {
        public Parameters();

        public static bool bGetParam(string paramName, bool paramDefault = false);
        public static void vSetParam(string paramName, bool paramDefault);
    }
}
```

Usage In C# Code:

```
var bPrm = Parameters.bGetParam("ParameterName", false);
```

Any suggestions to call bGetParam method by using JNA. Instead of calling INSTANCE.method, I need INSTANCE.Class.Method call.

Comment: You need to ensure you're using a "native" DLL rather than a "managed" DLL.  A "native" DLL provides a C-compatible API, while a "managed" DLL expects to be loaded from within the .NET framework.

Comment: I have read a bit more and creating a C++ wrapper seems a solution. 

I  found an example which C++ wrapper for C# dll is written already. By using Jnaerator tool, I auto-create the classes for Java and successfully called the functions from Java code for this example situation. 

The problem is I do not have any knowledge on C++ and can not create the header files etc on C++ for the dll I need. Is there any tool or library that auto creates C++ files for a C# dll?